# python web.py form - not getting any value

Tags: python, forms, web.py

I'm testing web.py and forms but I cant get any value in return. This is the code:

```
import web
from web import form
class add:
    def GET(self):
        f = login()
        return render.formtest(f)

    def POST(self): 
        f = login()
        print f["ip"].value
        return render.formpost(f)

render = web.template.render('templates/')      
login = form.Form(
    form.Textbox("ip", id="ip"),
    form.Textbox('snmp_community'),
)

urls = ( '/','index', '/add', 'add')
app = web.application(urls,globals())
if __name__ == "__main__": app.run()
```

I followed this example: http://webpy.org/form but when I print the value of f["ip"].value or f.d.ip I always get "None".

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you fix your indentation? As it stands now, this won't run.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a line from the  web.py doc:

> Note: You cannot access form values before having validated the form!

so you'll have to call f.validates() before you can access the posted data.

Comment: great, now it works! I missed that line on the documentation, thanks.